# how to access the client address in a socket.socket class list

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a server that access multiple esp8266 client. The server never closes so that it can always be connected to the clients. The server receives data from the clients. I can access the client socket information but I can't access the ip address of the client from the socket details. how can I pick the address from the list?

I am new in python programming and socket programming. I have printing the section in the socket list and it keeps bringing up error.

```
import socket
import selectors
sockInf = []

HOST = '192.168.1.170'
PORT = 8888

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()


class Message:
    def __init__(self, selector, sock, addr):
        self.selector = selector
        self.sock = sock
        self.addr = addr


def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('accepted connection from', addr)
    data = Message(sel, conn, addr)
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)


def recvData(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            recv_data = recv_data.decode('utf-8')
            if recv_data != " ":
                print(recv_data)
                print(sockInf[4])

        else:
            print('closing connection to', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()


def ip1Data(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    send_data = "hi client 1"
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        print(repr(send_data), 'to', data.addr)
        sock.send(send_data.encode('utf-8'))


def ip2Data(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    send_data = "hi client 2"
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        print(repr(send_data), 'to', data.addr)
        sock.send(send_data.encode('utf-8'))


lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
lsock.bind((HOST, PORT))
lsock.listen()
print('listening on', (HOST, PORT))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)


def runServer():
    try:
        event = sel.select(timeout=None)
        for key, mask in event:
            if key.data is None:
                accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
            else:
                recvData(key, mask)

    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("one of the clients have shut down!")
```

I expected it to print the ip address and the port number of the client but keeps bring up errors

```
File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    Main()
  File "main.py", line 6, in Main
    runServer()
  File "Server.py", line 77, in runServer
    recvData(key, mask)
  File "Server.py", line 35, in recvData
    print(sockInf[5])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

after researching about sockets I got a way of getting the ip Address through socket.getpername() function and my aim was to get the ip Address and send data to that ip, I used the socket.sendto() function.

```
def recvData(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            recv_data = recv_data.decode('utf-8')
            if recv_data != " ":
                print(recv_data)
                print(sock.getpeername())

        else:
            print('closing connection to', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
```